# Use a plugin like barcodescanner in nativescript vue

Tags: vue.js, nativescript, barcode-scanner, nativescript-vue

Im trying to use the barcodescanner plugin [here](https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-barcodescanner) with nativescript-vue so first i install it with npm like that in my project :

npm install nativescript-barcodescanner

then i register it in my src/main.js file :

Vue.registerElement('BarcodeScanner', () => require('nativescript-barcodescanner').BarcodeScanner)

And then  i tried many ways to include the scanner in my vue component but i always get an error. Does anyone knows how to use this component with nativescript vue ?

as an xml component it return a frame error :

```
<BarcodeScanner
  class="scanner-round"
  formats="QR_CODE, EAN_13"
  beepOnScan="true"
  reportDuplicates="true"
  preferFrontCamera="false"
  (scanResult)="onScanResult($event)">
</BarcodeScanner>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact we need to use normal javascript require to use this barcodescanner plugin like that :

```
const BarcodeScanner = require("nativescript-barcodescanner").BarcodeScanner;
```

and then inside a computed method :

```
var barcodescanner = new BarcodeScanner();
```

and then use this class :

```
barcodescanner
    .scan(
        {
            // Enter here your scanner preferences
        }
    )
    .then(
        result => {
            // handle here the barcode result.
        }
    )
```

Comment: I'm curious, I'm trying to implement Barcodescanner on nativescript-vue and I get the same frame error, I don't think your answer is clear... I did ``npm install -s nativescript-barcodescanner`` then I followed your answer, I dont understand about computed method without a function, it's just a variable.

Comment: You are the best !! :) Thank you for your solution !! :)